# ArrayList of PrintWriters and .get() method

Tags: java, arraylist, printwriter

I'm learning to use `ArrayList`s and `PrintWriter`s at the moment, and my professor has assigned us something where we must partition a file with the use of multiple `PrintWriter`s stored in an `ArrayList`. So I initialize the `Printwriter`s with a for loop that looks something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
  try {
    this.writers.add(new PrintWriter(new File(filePattern + i)));
  }
  catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    System.out.println("File " + i + " not found.");
  }
}
```

where `writers` is an `ArrayList<PrintWriter>` and `filePattern` is the source.
But in my `write` method I have to call on these `PrintWriter`s to actually write things. Using int `currentFile`, I rotate through the files to partition them, but I'm not exactly sure how to use a `PrintWriter` that's in an `ArrayList` when I haven't named it. Can I use the "get" method as follows? :

```
 public void write (String s) throws IOException {
  if (this.writers.size() > 0) {
    PrintWriter p = this.writers.get(currentFile);
    p.println(s);

    if (this.currentFile == (this.writers.size()-1)) {
      this.currentFile = 0;
    }
    else {
      this.currentFile++;
    }
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("No Writers currently exist");
  }
}
```

Or will that not work? And if not, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `this.writers.get(this.currentFile)` or `this.writers[this.currentFile]` which can still result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you don't check whether `this.currentFile` is between `0` and `this.writers.size()-1`. This should work for serial (i.e. non-parallel) execution.

Furthermore I advice to use getters to access your data (i.e. currentFile) and setters to change your data even in member methods as it is cleaner.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I'm used to using those, but for some reason, he hasn't specified it like in the last assignments, so I feel like he might want us to avoid using them for this one? I don't know, but I don't want to take the chance.
The .get() should work though? Like in my example, it should actually function properly?

Comment: @Azmera if you put some object references in a List and want to access these object references via indexing you can use the explicit get member method or overloaded operator[] (which is exactly the same "syntactic sugar"). Just take a look at the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html